# Export document library structure to file

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell, export

In a 2010 site colelction I have a document library with a complicated structure and lots of subfolders that I want to move to a flat structure. How can I get a hierarchical list of all (sub-)folders and all files? Maybe with powershell (v1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to get this information

```
Function GetFiles($folder)
{ 
    Write-Host $folder.Name
    foreach($file in $folder.Files)
    {
       Write-Host $file.Name
    }
    foreach ($subFolder in $folder.SubFolders)
    {
       GetFiles($Subfolder)
    }
}

$web = Get-SPWeb http://weburl
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
GetFiles($list.RootFolder)
```

Comment: It works with SP2013 but not in 2010 (ps 1.0), it doesn't find my site collection. How do I get this to work with my old SharePoint?

Comment: Have you loaded SharePoint Assemblies?

Comment: Yes, I have. Now it works. Looks like I didn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: Is it possible to sort the folders and file alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but others might find this question when looking it up. I figured out a very easy way:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-export-sharepoint-document-library-excel-show-folder-cardonick